# Ice with lead shot

Tags: buoyancy

A block of ice with a lead shot embedded in it is floating on water contained in a vessel. The temperature of the system is maintained at 0°C as the ice melts. 
What happens to the water level when the ice melts completely?
What would happen if the lead shot was not embedded in the ice?

I will add my thoughts on it:
I have always been confused with these questions.
As far as the lead shot is considered I think that it causes more rise in volume than it would normally do, if it was not embedded in ice, so the water level should decrease after the ice melts but the problem is that the ice melts and it may cause some volume changes on its own.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Is there anything in particular that makes you doubt your answer?  This is not a "do my homework/study examples" site.

Comment: Is the ice floating in pure water?

Answer (score 1):

To make matters simple assume we are dealing with pure water. The density of water changes with temperature as shown in the graph below with maximum density at 4 deg C, not too much different than 0 deg C, And you can see that for ice the density decreases below the freezing point; that's why ice floats.

[image]

Without lead shot the water level will remain the same as the ice melts. Why? - the amount of ice above the water that melts will exactly make up for the contraction of solid water that becomes liquid.

With enough lead shot to overcome buoyancy due to the expansion of ice crystals, the ice is pulled below the level of the water. As the ice melts, becomes liquid water, its volume contracts and so the level of the water will decrease.

Comment: I'll add that this question has been a topic of recent discussion regarding global warming, climate change and the concern for rising sea levels. Floating ice and ice that is held beneath the water by forces other than gravity each have different outcomes with regards of how they contribute to which direction sea level goes. I'm not sure scientists have a firm handle (high confidence) and there is disagreement on what this mix is.